# redirect using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have this location

```
http://somesite.com/pot_system.shtml
```

and i want to redirect to

```
http://somesite.com/build_me_today
```

I want to do this via htaccess is that possible

I used

```
Redirect /pot_system.shtml http://somesite.com/build_me_today
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way:

```
Redirect /pot_system.shtml /build_me_today
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a 301 redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /pot_system.shtml /build_me_today
```

Answer (score 1):

@Matt:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /pot_system.shtml http://somesite.com/build_me_today [R=301,L]
```