# URL redirect with files hosted (for short URL service)

Tags: html, url, redirect, dns, yourls

I have a URL with YOURLS URL shortening hosted on it. Currently when you visit the site you get a file list of all the YOURLS files (which is not ideal).

I would like to do a redirect so if people visit the site address they can be redirected elsewhere (as this won't be a public service).

I am hosted with Dreamhost and they already have a A-name record for the subdomain 'WWW' so I cannot add another A-name record for this. Also Dreamhost have advised that I could use DNS only and remove the hosting but obviously I need the hosting to host the YOURLS files. I have given up on their support team so hopefully someone here can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a .htaccess file to suit your needs.

You can use it to deny directory listing, see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932641/deny-directory-listing-with-htaccess). It will give visitors to www.yourdomain.whatever an error (access denied IIRC)

Or if you really to redirect them somewhere else you can try if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247200/redirect-using-htaccess) answer is helping you. Note that this redirects the user from one selected page to another.